# Why doesn't npm install react-native not work?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native

I'm trying to install react-native through `npm install --save react-native` for my library so I can export a react component that uses `View` as a wrapper around it's children to be platform agnostic. When I try to import `react-native` it spews hundreds of lines saying that it can't resolve modules in `react-native`

eg

`Error in ./~/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'ActivityIndicator'`

What's the best way to resolve this?

Comment: you'd better show a snapshot

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to install `react-native-cli` first using 
   `npm install -g react-native-cli`.
2. Then start your project by hitting the following- `react-native init YourProjectName`

For detailed information, follow their [guid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content)!

Comment: I'm writing a library, not a react-native application.

Comment: @PudgePacket did you solve issue? I'm also getting the same error.

Comment: @user43286 No sorry, What I did was remove the dependency on `react-native` from the library and make a separate version of the component that depended on react-native. That way people can opt into it by using that component specifically. This is assuming they have made a react-native app the traditional way though (with `react-native-cli`)

Answer (score 1):

delete package-lock.json file and node modules folder, then npm install.